# CoreBluetooth -- Discovery of BLE peripheral while device locked

Tags: objective-c, background-process, core-bluetooth

I've noticed, that the discovery of a BLE peripheral seems to behave different (on the central-side) when the device is in the *background* compared to when it's in the *background + locked*.

Can someone confirm this or point me to more information/documentation?

---

To be more specific -- when my app (central) is transitioning into the background and to the home-screen, it continues to discover peripherals as intended, but when I press the Sleep/Wake-button and thereby lock the device, it stops discovering my peripherals. The app is not crashing or anything... in fact, when I unlock the device (back to the home-screen), it resumes discovering peripherals without a need to bring it back to the foreground. I also understand, that BLE is triggered less frequently when in the background, but in my case I watched it in locked state for well over an hour and it never triggered a discovery, but once I unlock it's back to normal.

I am looking for a solution, where I also am able to discover a peripheral, when the device (running as central) is locked.

Thanks for your help!

-H

**Update...**

Found an interesting post and thought I'd share: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/lBeBkjSSTe5jAan6ufTX

Especially the observations (by Brian Fudge) are interesting...

> - A scanning device that is locked does not report any iOS peripherals that are also locked.
> - On some devices, like iPhone 5 and 5S, you only need to press the home button on the peripheral for the scanner to succeed and
>     peripherals to be reported.
> - On other devices, like iPad and iPod Touch, you have to press the home button and unlock the peripheral for the scanner to succeed and
>     peripherals to be reported.
> - A non-iOS device, such as an rMBP, can scan iOS peripherals that are in the background and locked.
> - All iOS devices can scan hardware peripherals (such as a health tracker) while the iOS device is in the background and locked.

Comment: Yes, it behaves differently. In background it is slowed down significantly and peripherals are discovered at most once (additional callbacks are filtered out). Discovering peripherals is tricky. Some details given in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20926722/768935 Search the net for this use case. It is documented quite well but in a "distributed way" :)

Comment: @allprog hi! thanks for your comment. yes, I've seen these and similar posts, but I am especially curious about the differences between 'background' & 'background + locked'. I've found an interesting conversation online and will add it to my post

Comment: The issues for bacground operation come mostly from a few factors: 1. the found duplicate peripherals are always filtered out, 2. the central must scan with service filtering, 3. the iOS peripheral removes the advertised services from the advertisement packets while backgrounded. I could not confirm the locked/unlocked difference yet. Would be great to get evidence that it work the way you describe. Recently someone reported it too but it didn't happen to me.

Comment: jep... I consider all of the mentioned things...

Comment: Actually, what is your concrete question? :)

Comment: I'd like to understand the concrete behavior of BLE discovery in different situations better, just like Brian Fudge wrote in his post, and get confirmation on my findings --> there's a difference between the central being in the background but unlocked (=Homescreen) and the device being locked.

I am able to discover a peripheral in the background when my device is unlocked, but not when it's locked.

I assume I am at the mercy of Apple changing the general behavior in this case, but IF there's a solution, I'd be interested to know. :)

Comment: In my case I wanted to keep the connection to one peripheral until the user explicitly disconnected it. Initially whenever the peripheral got out of range and got disconnected because of this I started a scanning in order to get the connection reestablished. But the scanning didn't work when in background mode. But then I found that if I just connected again using the existing peripheral instance then that worked in background. But if you are scanning for _any_ peripheral this approach will not help...

Comment: @JensSchwarzer unfortunately it doesn't help in this particular case, but thanks for sharing anyway!

Comment: @hschmied another option is to forward your question to the Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS) team. As an iOS developer you get two support requests per year included. Do it [here](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#techSupport).

Comment: Did you ask Apple DTS ? I'm stuck with this too, i need my app to perform some operations in background when it detect a particular BLE device, it's working if the app is in background but not if the device is locked.

Answer (score 3):

Ok i got the same problem and manage to understand why. So basically when you are in background or with the device locked, your app will be able to discover a device only one time (you can get multiple discovery in the foreground with the flag CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, but it's ignore in background)

So my app discovered without problems any BLE peripherals when it was in background but as soon as i locked my device i was unable to detect them. I figured out that the peripheral's broadcast packet is too huge (it was send in 2 times). Reducing my peripheral broadcast packet seems to fix the problem. When locked, the iPhone seems to listen to advertisement packet sent in one time. In foreground or background it is able to listen to packets send in 2 times.

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: Hi M, thanks for the input. Yeah, I noticed that the amount of detail that is sent varies depending on the app state. I basically ended up using [Vicinity](https://github.com/Instrument/Vicinity) in parallel with CoreBL and look forward to WWDC/iOS8.

But since you mentioned it... I might go back and give it a second (and refreshed) look when I've time.

Thx!

Comment: I'm still investigating on that problem but unfortunately i haven't found a good way to solve it. Basically if you broadcast in a discoverable mode (every 20ms), with the device locked it could take at least a minute to detect the device. I update the broadcast interval to 1sec and it could take between 10 sec to several hour to detect it. So i haven't found a way to detect the peripheral with a lock device in a reasonable advertisement time. I hope iOS 8 will improve this behaviour...